# Get binary size of particular String JAVA

Tags: java, string

How to get a binary size of a String(for example String s = "Ababa") in BITS(not bytes).

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowledge about encoding. Maybe tell us more about what do you need that for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

get bytes, mutiply by 8...

```
"xxx".getBytes().length * 8;
```

Edit: merging with the answer of Jon Skeet, it's could be also important to specify the encoding, otherwise this will return the size using the system's default encoding, and that's not necessarily what you want to know. To know the size using a certain encoding, use:

```
 "xxx".getBytes(encoding).length * 8;
```

encoding being "UTF-8", "ASCII", or whatever you want to use.

Comment: @RobertKilar If answer time of one question is 14min ago, and another 15 minutes ago which answer was earlier?

Answer (score 10):

In what encoding? The number of *bits* of a particular binary representation of a string is just the number of bytes * 8:

```
byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8"); // Or whatever encoding you want
int bits = bytes.length * 8;
```

I don't think I've ever seen an encoding which allows fractions of a byte.

Note that if you're interested in UTF-16, you can just use `text.length() * 16` as each `char` is a UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: Hi Jon, aren't Java strings internally represented by two-byte characters?

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz: Yes, but that's somewhat irrelevant - or at least, it's not what the OP asked. It's a very vague question at the moment.

Comment: @RobertKilar: Actually, my answer was before lxx's (14:07:37 vs 14:08:25) - not that it really matters. Pick the *better* answer; a minute either way isn't important.

Comment: Do you mean `bytes.length` and `text.length()`?

Comment: @Ixx: On the other hand, it uses the platform-default encoding rather than specifying one, which is almost *always* the wrong approach. I definitely *wouldn't* use that code.

Comment: uhm, well, yes. Mostly you would have set some encoding for the application / program and you want to know the size using this encoding, of course, not the system's default.

Comment: @Ixx: By "you would have set some encoding" - you mean change the system default? Ick, no thanks. I'd rather be explicit every time I want to use an encoding.

Comment: I meant if more like "define"... sorry, "set" is misleading.